# How should we represent an IPv6 address with port number in text?

Tags: ipv6

Under IPv4, the *de facto* standard notation `10.1.2.3:1234` is completely clear: it is an IP address with port number. This is understood in URL's for instance: `http://10.1.2.3:1234/doc.xhtml`.

If I have a `sockaddr_ipv4` class in some code, its `tostring` method can return this colon notation and everything is cool.

In a fit of myopia, the designers for the IPv6 addresses numeric notation decided that the colon character was available for their use as a separator. As a result, a colon-delimited port number looks ambiguous on an IPv6 address.

How can we incorporate a port number into a printed representation of an IPv6 address-with-port? Is there some *de facto* standard way?

Comment: [Boom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186829/how-do-ports-work-with-ipv6) and [bam](http://serverfault.com/questions/205793/how-can-one-distinguish-the-host-and-the-port-in-an-ipv6-url)

Comment: I think what @Ordous is trying to say is that this question is a duplicate of some existing questions with answers :)

Comment: @Ordous ...and, of course, [bang](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5436548/839601)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of any question *here*; those are off topic on those sites. The question isn't about a broken piece of code, so it's not appropriate for StackOverflow, and it's not a sysadmin issue for ServerFault. It's a "conceptual questions about software development": what do I put into the `tostring` method of an IPv6 socket address class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The common way of doing this is to enclose the IPv6 address in square brackets like this:

```
[2001:db8::1]:8080
```

This is what is being used in URLs for example:

```
http://[2001:db8::1]:8080/
```

Comment: You forgot to copy over the RFC reference from the SO answer. :)

Comment: In fact RFC 5952 has a more well-rounded answer in section 6. The `[ADDR]:PORT` isn't the only notation; just the one that should be used in URLs according to RFC 3986.

Comment: For instance, it turns out that this is acceptable, for an IPv6 mapped IPv6: `::ffff:10.1.2.3:1234`, without the square brackets. (Though that is not valid in URL use, it is not ambiguous.)